fastboot throws a FAILED (remote: Warning: battery capacity is very low) when trying to write/erase

Phone: Realme X3 SuperZoom 8/128
fastboot: version eac51f2bb6a8-android
PC OS: Windows 10

When trying to install TWRP, I got Bootloop(Does not exit the Bootloader, does not even power off).
I tried to flash another recovery.img, but I got an error.
C:\Windows\system32>fastboot flash recovery C:\platform-tools\recovery.img
target reported max download size of 805306368 bytes
sending 'recovery' (81920 KB)...
OKAY [  2.376s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: Warning: battery's capacity is very low)
finished. total time: 2.384s

Since the phone is stuck in the bootloader, it is not possible to charge it to the desired state.

I was looking for a solution by error- there are no solutions for phones
There is nothing in fastboot --help that could help
I couldn't find tools like fastboot to work with bootloader


Sorry, but I think recovering your device while the battery is low is impossible. I'm not entirely sure

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
